# How to pass location using XMPP in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, xmpp

I have to pass location using XMPP. How can I do it?

Comment: Hello you can used  stack link to send location to user 
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982752/how-to-send-location-to-other-user-in-xmpp-swift-3-0

Answer (score 3):

As I am give you suggestion regarding single chat. as you are prepare xml formate for sending message in `XMPP` as like bellowed.

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:textvalue];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
[message addChild:body];

[[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

Here add two extra attribute for `latitude` and `longitude` as like below.

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:textvalue];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"latitude" stringValue:@"22.2345"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"longitude" stringValue:@"42.2345"];
[message addChild:body];

[[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

there won't be any problem in sending message while adding two extra parameter. and at other end while received this message you can fetched `latitude` and `longitude` from message and used it as per your requirements.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Which XEP does that follow?

Comment: @FrederickNord, it may be xep-0313 or xep-0022.

Comment: It's strange that I couldn't find "latitude" in either of those XEPs.